# is sqlite-net-pcl library support one to many or many to many relationship - Xamarin

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms, sqlite-net-pcl

I am totally new to xamarin form and I want to create one to many relationships with sqlite-net-pcl library. Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLiteNetExtensions/

Comment: @Jason I have explicitly said sqlite-net-pcl library and you gave me SQLiteNETExtension library, in addition, you also downvoted my question.

Comment: "SQLite-Net Extensions is a very simple ORM that provides one-to-one, one-to-many, many-to-one, many-to-many, inverse and text-blobbed relationships on top of the sqlite-net library."

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean something like this?

```
public class Person
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public Person()
    {

    }
}

public class Pet
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int PersonID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Pet()
    {

    }
}
```